# Restricted areas in embedded template edit in Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

Is there a way to restrict user access to edit the only selected template in Docusign Embedded Template Edit? Currently by `CreateEditView` URL users can see the top menu and also navigate to another template.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqgyP.png)

If not, what is the best way to achieve it assuming our customers should be able to edit their own paperwork template?

Comment: I'm facing EXACTLY the same challenge, please let me know if you discover anything useful, I'll do the same